# Maximum number of users use in utility.sendmail function in SharePoint CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

What is the maximum limit of users use in to address of SharePoint utility.sendmail function in SharePoint Client side?

Comment: did you find any issue ? I don't think it is documented anywhere on limits of users in To address.

Comment: Yes, I have more than. 100 users but didn't send mail properly for all users if less than 100 users then it's working.

Comment: oho..may be then you can divide requests in 2,3 parts....

Comment: Yes but I want to know whether there is any limitations or not?